# Is PostgreSQL auto cast from Numeric to String reliable

Tags: postgresql

I have this query:

```sql
select p.id from Project p where p.id like CONCAT('%', :projectId);
```

The parameter projectId is a nullable long type (in java Long). So either this parameter has a value (12345) or is null. So the reason behind this is that a user CAN pass a value for projectId or not.

This query works in general.

For my understanding, PostgreSQL does an auto-cast from long to string to use the like function.

Does this mechanism work reliable?

By reliable i mean is this intended to work now and in the future?
In short: Can i use this behaviour without a doubt?

My concrete problem is an individual user search page where it can select up to 6 search parameters or even 0 search parameters.

That are basically 6! options - a lot of work (switch/if) and so on ...

EDIT:
Problem with this approach is:

```sql
select p.id from Project p where p.id like CONCAT('%', '2');
```

yields projects with id of:
2, 22, 222, 22222 and so on.

This might not what you want.

Maybe you can improve it like this:

```sql
select p.id from Project p where p.id like ':projectId';
```

where you put the actual number 1234 as parameter or '%"

Comment: Clean and safe with an explicit cast: `WHERE p.id LIKE CONCAT('%', :projectId::text)`

Comment: "*auto-cast from long to string to use the like function*" - no, it does it for the `concat` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're describing, where PostgreSQL automatically converts a Java Long parameter to a string when used in a LIKE query, is not mandated by the SQL standard and might differ depending on factors like database version and setup. It's advised to explicitly manage the conversion in your code in order to assure dependability and future-proofing. To change your code, follow these steps:

```
Long projectId = ...; // Get the projectId from user input or elsewhere

String projectIdString = (projectId != null) ? projectId.toString() : null;

String queryString = "SELECT p.id FROM Project p WHERE p.id LIKE CONCAT('%', :projectId)";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("projectId", projectIdString);

List<Long> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: How `setParameter` handles a long does not depend on the database setup but rather on the choice of query library/ORM